# How to read local files in the Google Cloud Functions emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

My Google Cloud Function needs to read a local file (an image).
I've added the image in the function directory tree, so I have:

```
packages.json
src/functions.js
lib/functions.js
img/shower.png
```

This is the code I'm using to read it:

```
var img = await new Jimp.read("../img/shower.png")
```

Now, when the function triggers, I'm getting this:
`2017-03-30T03:00:25.118Z - error: (node:1685) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../img/shower.png'`

I've tried moving the image around, eg to the directory where my function resides (`lib/`) with no luck.

I've also logged `process.cwd()` which returned an unexpected: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator`

Any hints?

Comment: Sounds like they're doing an npm install -g.

Comment: (my suggestion is to experiment with what that does locally... hell, if you're really desperate, I'm sure you can put the img in lib/image.js and it will be there :) . The other interesting thing to do would be to run a complete directory listing from the root...)

Comment: Ok, I'll strace it..

Answer (score 4):

Well, the trick is just reading the file from the absolute path

`Jimp.read(__dirname + "img/shower.png")`

This is the documentation for [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname)