# Cloud Function robots.txt 404 page not found issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, robots.txt

I have deployed one simple app via go language in Cloud Function.

*A robots.txt file is also included when distributing the app.

[image]

In this regard, a simple app normally shows the image below.
[image]

But it shows 404 page not found even though the robots.txt file is normal.
[image]

Does anyone know if the robots.txt file itself can't be served by Cloud Function?

##Function.go

```
// Package p contains an HTTP Cloud Function.
package p

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// HelloWorld prints the JSON encoded "message" field in the body
// of the request or "Hello, World!" if there isn't one.
func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var d struct {
        Message string `json:"message"`
    }

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&d); err != nil {
        switch err {
        case io.EOF:
            fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello World!")
            return
        default:
            log.Printf("json.NewDecoder: %v", err)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
    }

    if d.Message == "" {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello World!")
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, html.EscapeString(d.Message))
}
```

##go.mod

```
module example.com/cloudfunction
```

##robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Allow: /
```

Thank you in advance to those who have responded.

Comment: Can you share your cloud function code here

Comment: @Prany Thanks for the reply.

I have entered the function code in the current post, so please check it.

Comment: I'm not good in Golang but I dont see the file path of the txt file. see this answer here where they have tried to read files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117124/how-to-read-local-files-in-the-google-cloud-functions-emulator

Comment: Cloud Functions is not a web server. Why are you concerned with robots.txt? If your endpoint is public, you will receive a large number of requests for URLs that do not exist. Review @Ferregina's answer for how to add routing to your app if you do want to handle sending a response for robots.txt. Also, review the differences between applications that behave as web servers versus API servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cloud Functions is not a web server**.

You cannot just add files and expect those will be served as you would you do it with an NGINX or Apache web server.

When you reach your CF endpoint the code you added will be executed and you'll get a result from that and in any case the files you add will be used by the code but not served.

I'd suggest to first understand what Cloud Functions is [intended for](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview) and as an alternative you may want to go with [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs).

Another way to go is to use a workaround to handle the routes and that all stuff as *guillaume* shows in this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-multiple-paths-in-cloud-functions-python-and-flask-fc6780e560d3) for Python + Flask:

```py
from flask import Flask, request

#Define an internal Flask app
app = Flask("internal")

#Define the internal path, idiomatic Flask definition
@app.route('/user/<string:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def users(id):
    
    print(id)
    return id, 200

#Comply with Cloud Functions code structure for entry point
def my_function(request):
    
    #Create a new app context for the internal app
    internal_ctx = app.test_request_context(path=request.full_path,
                                            method=request.method)
    
    #Copy main request data from original request
    #According to your context, parts can be missing. Adapt here!
    internal_ctx.request.data = request.data
    internal_ctx.request.headers = request.headers
    
    #Activate the context
    internal_ctx.push()
    
    #Dispatch the request to the internal app and get the result 
    return_value = app.full_dispatch_request()
    
    #Offload the context
    internal_ctx.pop()
    
    #Return the result of the internal app routing and processing      
    return return_value
```

And it is important what he mentions at the end:

> However, keep in mind that’s a workaround, even a hack, and Cloud Functions aren’t designed for this purpose.

Here's a sample [for Go](https://blog.gonzih.me/blog/2019/01/18/routing-with-go-on-google-cloud-functions/):

```golang
package function

import (
    "net/http"
)

var mux = newMux()

//F represents cloud function entry point
func F(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func newMux() *http.ServeMux {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/one", one)
    mux.HandleFunc("/two", two)
    mux.HandleFunc("/subroute/three", three)

    return mux
}

func one(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("hello from one"))
}

func two(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("hello from two"))
}

func three(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("hello from three"))
}
```

Comment: <3 I love your Go example <3 I also answered a hack for serving file in Go with Cloud Function. The 2 answers combined can be powerful, but overkill for a simple function!

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Functions isn't a webserver and you can't serve file directly like that. You need to process them in Go.

For that you need to know the code structure of the functions. All the original files are stored in `/workspace/serverless_function_source_code` directory. So, you can simply serve them using the URL path like that

```
var functionSourceCodeDir = "/workspace/serverless_function_source_code"

func ServeFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    file := r.URL.Path
    if file == "/" {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "you must provide a file pathname")
        return
    }
    http.ServeFile(w, r, functionSourceCodeDir+file)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
We will test it based on your answers.